# Win 10 update causes BLACK SCREEN (Macbook Pro with Boot Camp)

Tags: windows-10, boot-camp, windows-10-upgrade

I have a MacBook Pro. Created a new boot camp partition and installed Win 7 Pro. Performed all updates. Upgraded to Win 10. Seemed to work fine.

I saw there was an update so I updated and it asked me to reboot. Now, when I reboot I get a BLACK SCREEN (no cursor, etc). Any solutions you can think of? I heard a little "Windows" start chime when the screen was black but I can't see or do anything.

I tried hitting ENTER and logging in, but couldn't get anywhere with that.

Searching online I see alot of links about black screen with seeing the cursor but that is not the case here. Also I don't think it matters, but I am running boot camp, but this is a separate partition on my MBP drive.

***** UPDATE *****
Running: MacBook Pro 8,1 (13 inch, early 2011; 2.3 Ghz Intel Core i5); OSX El Capitan Version 10.11.1; Bootcamp Assistant 6.0.0; Summary: Win 7 Pro installed & activated fine. Win 10 upgraded fine. The UPDATE seemed to work but upon reboot screen is BLACK.

Thanks

Comment: The update to what exactly?  What was the update precisely?  Have you tried Safe Mode?

Comment: 2011 MBP is not supported for  Win 10 - see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204990

Comment: Strictly speaking if Windows 8.1 x64 works then Windows 10 x64 will work the system requirements if I am not mistaken are identical.  The problem described also does not sound like a hardware incompatibility.  [Windows 8.1 x64](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201457) was indeed supported.  The only possible reason this happens would be because of a display driver problem, which goes back to, Boot Camp display drivers supporting or not supporting your hardware.  Be sure Boot Camp and OS X are the current version.

Comment: I think you're right. Early 2011 is not supported. BUT, Win 10 did install ok and boot up fine. It was when I did the UPDATE and then rebooted that I got the black screen. :(

Answer (score 0):

I started experiencing the same issue on my MBPr 2015 running Bootcamp. Since a recent update of Win10, when I undock my laptop at home (where I use an external monitor) and reboot it, it seems like Win10 still expects an external monitors, so the screen goes dark. An extra reboot fixes it, but I had to learn the steps to reboot it in the dark.

Comment: The original question doesn't say anything about external monitors, so I don't think this really answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this Issue by Changing the Brightness on a different Screen that I attached before.

So attach your MacBook to a External Monitor go down with the brightness a little bit the screen goes on..

But you have to do it also when the second display is disconnected so I tried to do it with a black screen was not easy but it work

Answer (score -1):

Paolo Tosolini is on to something! - Pressing enter or any series of key commands did nothing - even booting off the flash drive or attempting Safe mode did nothing. It wasn't until forcing the PC to reboot normally from within windows IN THE DARK (meaning with a black screen) it worked!

I waited for windows to finish booting even though I couldn't see anything on the screen, then i performed the following to reboot windows - without seeing what i'm doing!

Press the Command key to open the start menu.
type "shutdown -r -t 0" and then press enter
this is the command to tell windows to reboot with a timer of 0 seconds.

After windows rebooted, the screen came on and everything now shows proper.

Thanks for the suggestion! Hope this helps!